# Email-to-case: Case not visible in the Account

Tags: email2case

I have set up Case-to-email and am testing it in my sandbox.  The Case gets created as expected and the Contact is properly populated and the Account to which the Contact belongs is reflected in the Case Details screen - So far so good!

However when I go to the Account, the Case does not show in the Cases related objects section.  Interestingly the Activity History section of the Account shows the Email that was received for the new Case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you 100 % sure the account you are looking at is the same? If so, go to the account page layout (edit) and see if there is another case related list hidden. Those are the 2 scenarios in which I have seen this happening.

Comment: echoing PepeFloyd, be sure to traverse from the Case detail page to the Account, not via searching

Comment: I am going directly to the Account Page and not doing a search...  When I go to the Case related list on the Account Page the case is not there... however the Case is reflected in the Activity History related list on the Account.  If I Go to the Cases Tab the Case is visible and on the case details page the Account is populated... Perhaps there is a very long lag before the Case gets attached?

Comment: Just noticed something strange: WE have two fields on the Case for Account... One is the standard field "Account" which is a Lookup field. This field gets populated when the case is created.  The other field is a Custom field called "End User Account" which is also a Lookup field.  When I manually populate this field the Case is now visible in the Account Case related list.  Why would the Custom field populate the Account related list and not the Standard field which is obviously linked to the Contact record which generated the Case?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem of you.

Go to the hidden menu at the right of your page, then click *Edit Layout* going to the *Page Layout* Editing page. Then, from the Panel, go to the Related List section. At the right of the Panel you will find the Standard Case (**Case**) and a Custom Case (**Casi**, in the attached image). If you add Case on the Page Layout you will see that "the Case from the mail" will be visible on the new Related List.

[image]